# Can't keep or/and load image in Excel using openpyxl after bundling the application with pyinstaller

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, openpyxl

Using the openpyxl library, I am loading an Excel, adding values in it and I save it in another file.
It is working nicely.

Problem: when I use the library pyinstaller to bundle the application, the images aren't load and keep in the file anymore when the new file is saved.
PS :

- I tried to let the images in the file, it doesn't work.
- I tried to load the images with openpyxl, it doesn't work too.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input_file.xlsx')
ws = wb['excel_tab_name']

image = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('my_image.jpg')
image.anchor = 'A1'
ws.add_image(image)
wb.save('output_file.xlsx')
```

The real problem is that it work when I use only openpyxl but when I bundle it, no image can stay or be loaded in the file.

I am ready to use another library to handle this problem if it is needed ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just try and catch the error.
If it's "you must install pillow to fetch image objects"
Use `pip install image`

And that's it !

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like this and it worked. Is this answering your question ?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input_path.xlsx')
ws = wb['excel_tab_name']

image = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('my_image.jpg')
image.anchor = 'A1'
ws.add_image(image)
wb.save('output_path.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! need to change the op. too. (I edited my code)
But no it's not the problem I'm facing.
The problem arrive when I use pyinstaller.

Comment: I tried that code having input_path.xlsx and my_image.jpg in the same folder as the exe and it worked like a charm. Can you tell waht is different with your setup

Comment: I took a break and I used try except to watch out the error.
"you must install pillow to fetch image objects"
Now it's work like a charm too !

Thanks for the help, I took "du recul" on the situation with your intervention :)